# Envoy access logs duration fields

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

We are using access logs fields to provide durations type
We are using the following

```
totalDuration: '%DURATION%'
upstreamTime: '%RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)%'
```

We are getting the values, however its **identical value** (exact same time ) in the access logs,, why? I guess that the duration should always be greater the upstram_service_time
What am I missing here?

```
1 We need the total time of the calls E2E - for that we use '%DURATION%'
2. How much time it spent e2e on the upstream '%RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)%'
```

Is it possible to print microseconds ?  maybe there we could see the differences

Comment: Please don't reuse an existing question to ask another one. You should instead post a new question, and either answer this yourself if you've found an answer or solution, or delete it if you don't think the question is valid or all that valuable anymore.